# Connect to socket Qlik Sense Entreprise with EnigmaJS

Tags: websocket, qliksense

I build a working mashup on QlikSense Desktop connecting with the usual:

```
appId = 'engine';
this.session = enigma.create({
    schema,
    url: 'ws://localhost:4848/app/' + appId
})
```

But now I uploaded the mashup on the server, and for once, it behaves as expected. It doesn't.
I tried to change it to the following as the server doesn't have SSL certificates.

```
'ws://domainname:4747/'+appId
```

But nothing works, any idea ?

(Basically my question is: How can I find my QIX Engine ws url ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats the error?

But in general, when using QS server you have to be authenticated in order to get some data.

You can check all the received data by listening to all traffic for more details on the error:

`session.on('traffic:received', data => console.log('received:', data));`

Or you can just "listen" to data related only to authentication by setting a dedicated notification:

```js
session.on('notification:OnAuthenticationInformation', (authInfo) => {
  console.log(authInfo)
});
```

Have a look at [Connecting to the Qlik Engine JSON API](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/November2019/Subsystems/EngineAPI/Content/Sense_EngineAPI/GettingStarted/connecting-to-engine-api.htm) (scroll down to `Qlik Sense Enterprise` section) to get the idea what types of authentication are supported

Comment: So, even tho the mashup is on the server running under QlikSense I need to authenticate the ws connection between my mashup and the QIX ? I dont know anything about certificates so that's gonna be fun. Thanks, I'll look into all of it.

Comment: If you are using the Capabiliy API you dont need authentication (because Qlik will deal with it prior your mashup is loaded) but if you just upload a webpage and want to open enigma connection - you need to authenticate in order to get a session (although your mashup is on QS you are trying to open a new session with enigma). Now be very, very, very careful with certificates! Advise you to use certificates only as backend service (server to server). Certificates grants the FULL permissions over the system! In mashup environment try and use some other way of authentication

Comment: So now I get the OnAuthenticationInformation method response. I can fetch global but, after more than one fetch  I get the `mustAuthenticate: true` again. So I can't do session.open().then(global=> global.getDocList().then(.... Any other useful tips?

Comment: the `OnAuthenticationInformation` response will also give you the login url. So the workflow is: if `mustAuthenticate:true` -> redirect the user to the login page -> once logged in -> qlik will redirect back to the mashup with the `qlikTicket` in the url -> extract the ticket from the url and use it in enigma. You need to specify the `reloadUri` (in your case this will be the mashuop url) have a look at this code https://github.com/qlik-oss/enigma.js/blob/ee0475d3bf1be132f9b769a6b9f940f261532275/examples/complete/car-models/src/app.js#L39

Comment: OR im guessing you can parse the url for `qlikTicket` parameter and pass this ticket to enigma

Comment: So using that method you'd be prompted to enter you username and password when you try to connect to the websocket. Then, once connected you filter the url for a token. No certificates, no virtual proxies needed? Most of the answers in Qlik's doc point toward those kind of horror.

Comment: certificates and headers are ok if you just prototyping or playing. personally im using certificates ONLY if there is no user involved. For example to perform some automation (server not in the cluster is connecting to qlik. and not user are interacting with this server). Using the `reloadUri` method (and "scrapping" the ticket from the url) you are leaving the authentication to be handled between the user and qlik and your code is just using the result of this interaction. I think that this is much more safer than exposing cert/headers in your (public) code

Comment: Ive tested this approach and its working fine. I have an issue using this method when my mashup is hosted on 3rd party server (hosted by IIS/apache/nginx). Somehow this approach is not working in all the cases. I have an open issue with qlik at the moment to make it work ... just saying